# Manifest merger failed with errors, Attribute provider#androidx.core.content.FileProvider@authorities at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder

Tags: android

I am developing an android application and constantly, when I run my application, I am getting an error: Installation did not succeed.

The application could not be installed and also I have errors in AndroidManifest.xml file that is "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs".

The AndroidManifest.xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.connectsocialmediaapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name="Activities.MainContentPage"></activity>
        <activity android:name="Activities.RegisterPage" />
        <activity android:name="Activities.LoginPage" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:authorities="${com.example.connectsocialmediaapp}.here.this.library.provider"
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">

        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

below in Merged Manifest I have the detailed information of this error as well which is:

> Error: Attribute provider#androidx.core.content.FileProvider@authorities at AndroidManifest.xml:24:13-98 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <com.example.connectsocialmediaapp> is provided. ConnectSocialMediaApp.app main manifest (this file), line 23 Error: Validation failed, exiting ConnectSocialMediaApp.app main manifest (this file)

Answer (score 0):

`com.example.connectsocialmediaapp` seems to be the value of `applicationId` for that app.

Try using:

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.here.this.library.provider"
```

instead of the current `android:authorities` value.